# Ansible: how to print var name while looping?

Tags: ansible

I have this inside `setup/tasks/apps.yml`:

```
- name: Mac App Store | Install apps.
  shell: mas list | grep {{ item.id }} || mas install {{ item.id }}
  with_items: "{{ mac_store_apps }}"
  register: result
  changed_when: result.stdout.find('Installed') != -1
```

I know I can use:

```
      loop_control:
        label: '{{ item.name }}'
```

But I want to print something like:

> Attempting to Install `{{ item.name }}`

before each execution. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to generate output *before* each iteration of your loop; Ansible only produces output when a task (or an iteration of a looping task) is complete.  If you are concerned that package installation can take a while and you want to provide some feedback, you could just print out a notice in advance, as in:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Note: package installation may take several minutes to complete"
```

You can sort of get what you want by placing your install task in a separate file, and then calling `include_tasks` in a loop. For example, if we have the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mac_store_apps:
      - name: foo
      - name: bar
      - name: baz
      - name: qux
  tasks:
    - name: "Mac App Store | Install apps."
      include_tasks: ./install.yml
      with_items: "{{ mac_store_apps }}"

    - debug:
        var: all_results
```

And the following tasks in `install.yml`:

```
---
- name: "Mac App Store | Install {{ item.name }}"
  shell: "true"
  register: result

- name: Store result
  set_fact:
    all_results: "{{ all_results|default([]) + [{'item': item, 'result': result}] }}"
```

We will see as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Mac App Store | Install apps.] **********************************************************
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/install.yml for localhost => (item={u'name': u'foo'})
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/install.yml for localhost => (item={u'name': u'bar'})
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/install.yml for localhost => (item={u'name': u'baz'})
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/install.yml for localhost => (item={u'name': u'qux'})

TASK [Mac App Store | Install foo] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Store result] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Mac App Store | Install bar] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Store result] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Mac App Store | Install baz] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Store result] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Mac App Store | Install qux] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Store result] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_results": [
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "foo"
            }, 
            "result": {
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "true", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.002398", 
                "end": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.146497", 
                "failed": false, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.144099", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        }, 
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "bar"
            }, 
            "result": {
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "true", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.002245", 
                "end": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.285859", 
                "failed": false, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.283614", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        }, 
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "baz"
            }, 
            "result": {
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "true", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.002406", 
                "end": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.426909", 
                "failed": false, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.424503", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        }, 
        {
            "item": {
                "name": "qux"
            }, 
            "result": {
                "changed": true, 
                "cmd": "true", 
                "delta": "0:00:00.002232", 
                "end": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.574214", 
                "failed": false, 
                "rc": 0, 
                "start": "2019-04-23 11:19:25.571982", 
                "stderr": "", 
                "stderr_lines": [], 
                "stdout": "", 
                "stdout_lines": []
            }
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=13   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0
```